# Java card 3 vendors, any cards available?

Tags: javacard

I'm looking for java cards running 3.0 with 64k or more (128 is better) of NV memory.  I can't find any card manufacturers who make such a card...

Even a Java card 2.0 with 128k would be helpful.

thanks!

--Steve

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Answer (score 2):

None that I know of. 2.2.2 cards with 128K are available though, for example Oberthur Cosmo v7

Comment: I assume you are referring to the "Oberthur ID-One Cosmo V7".

Answer (score 2):

http://javacos.com/javacardos.php

You can found what you what. Or contact me directly.

We provide cards or keys support classic 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Gemalto TOP IM GX has 72Kb of EEPROM memory for applets.  It is JC 2.2.1, GP 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard of cards running Java Card 3. I did not even hear/receive prototypes of such cards.

The probably newest one (according to API versions) with that amount of memory is the NXP J3A128 v.2.4.1 R3 running JCOP 2.4.1.

Two months ago I got told, that this fall the same chip with JCOP version 2.4.2 is to be shipped. This card/OS implements Java Card 2.2.2 and GlobalPlatform 2.1.1

Answer (score 1):

I have the Java card 3 in stock with standard VOP-keys; samples can be ordered here:

http://www.motechno.com/javacard3.0.html

Answer (score 1):

Yubikey NEO contains a JavaCard 3.0.1 chip inside.

Answer (score 0):

Yubikey NEO：
the YubiKey NEO with just the HID (keyboard) USB device enabled.  We did this to maximise compatibility with the YubiKey Standard and the pre-production YubiKey NEO – neither of which support SmartCard functions.  To enable the OpenPGP SmartCard function, you need to configure the YubiKey NEO to switch on the CCID interface.  So far, we have updated the ykpersonalize command line to support the “-m” switch; this controls the composite modes the YubiKey NEO exhibits. Be careful, you can use the -m command to remove HID support; as ykpersonalize only works with through the HID interface, this means you cannot use ykpersonalize anymore if you remove HID support.  We have added the tool ykneo-ccid-modeswitch which allows you to enable HID if it gets removed!